# How to add class in first post?

Tags: php, wordpress

Here my code, now i want add "active" class in first post. Some Please help me solve this. i used $i for adding new class.

```
<?php         
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'cc_testimonial', 'posts_per_page' => 1, "order" => "DESC");
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $cc = count($query);
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) { 
    $query->the_post();
?>
<?php for($i = 0; $i<$cc; $i++){ ?>
                    <div class="testimonialitem item <?php echo ($i==0)?'active':'' ?>">
                        <div class="testimonial-content">
                            <p><?php the_title( );?></p>
                        </div>                          
                    </div><!--/.testimonialitem-->                      


<?php    
}
            }
        }
        wp_reset_query();
        wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: are you getting any error

Comment: That should already work, what's the final HTML that you see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For applying active class to your FIRST post , try below code:

```
<?php         
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'cc_testimonial', 'posts_per_page' => 1, "order" => "DESC");
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$cc = count($query);
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
$i=0;
while ( $query->have_posts() ) { 
$query->the_post();
<div class="testimonialitem item <?php echo ($i==0)?'active':''; ?>">
                    <div class="testimonial-content">
                        <p><?php the_title( );?></p>
                    </div>                          
                </div><!--/.testimonialitem-->       
      $i++; 
       }
    }
    wp_reset_query();
    wp_reset_postdata();
   ?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try following code:

```
<?php         
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'cc_testimonial', 'posts_per_page' => 1, "order" => "DESC");
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$cc = count($query);
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
$i=0;
while ( $query->have_posts() ) { 
$query->the_post();
<div class="testimonialitem item <?php echo ($i==0)?'active':'' ?>">
                    <div class="testimonial-content">
                        <p><?php the_title( );?></p>
                    </div>                          
                </div><!--/.testimonialitem-->       
      $i++; 
       }
    }
    wp_reset_query();
    wp_reset_postdata();
   ?>
```

Comment: Like to enlighten us what changes were made?

Comment: have removed for loop and just used $i

Answer (score 0):

more easy to add class for first item using jquery.

Try this:

```
`$('.testimonialitem:first').addClass('active');`
```